# Exponential object in the category of simple, undirected graphs

Tags: ct.category-theory, graph-theory

Let $G_i = (V_i, E_i)$ be  simple, undirected graphs for  $i=1,2$. A *graph homomorphism* is a map $f:V_1\to V_2$ such that $\{f(v), f(w)\}\in E_2$ whenever $\{v,w\}\in E_1$.

By $\text{Hom}(G_1, G_2)$ we denote the collection of graph homomorphisms from $G_1$ to $G_2$. Note that it is possible that $\text{Hom}(G_1, G_2)=\emptyset$.

[This paper](http://groupoids.org.uk/pdffiles/graphmorphisms-v15i1a1.pdf) is supposed to describe how we can make $\text{Hom}(G_1, G_2)$ into a graph - but I can't flesh out a criterion for: when do $f, g \in \text{Hom}(G_1, G_2)$ form an edge?

Comment: I don't read the paper, but how about considering free groupoids $\mathcal{G}_1$, $\mathcal{G}_2$ generated by $G_1$, $G_2$ and then taking appropriate subgraph of the underlying graph of the category $\textbf{Cat}(\mathcal{G}_1,\mathcal{G}_2)$?

Comment: Good point - I think that this exactly amounts to what is described in the answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The title of your question asks about "exponential object[s] in the category of simple, undirected graphs". I can tell you what they are.

(The body of your question asks about a construction in a specific paper, which I haven't read, so I can't answer *that* question directly. But of course, exponentials are unique when they exist.)

So: in the category of simple graphs that you mention, the exponentials $\mathrm{HOM}(G_1, G_2)$ are as follows. A vertex of $\mathrm{HOM}(G_1, G_2)$ is a function from the set of vertices of $G_1$ to the set of vertices of $G_2$. Two vertices $\phi, \psi$ of $\mathrm{HOM}(G_1, G_2)$ are adjacent iff whenever $x$ and $y$ are adjacent vertices of $G_1$, then $\phi(x)$ and $\psi(y)$ are adjacent vertices of $G_2$.

I'd recommend Godsil and Royle's book *Algebraic Graph Theory*. [This blog post](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2014/12/graph_colouring_and_cartesian.html) also says more about the cartesian closed category of simple graphs.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the useful link to the blog post you wrote!

Comment: As a point of clarification: In your answer you say that vertices are graph homomorphisms, but the post you link says that a vertex is _any_ function on the underlying sets.

Comment: Oops! Corrected now. Thanks.

Comment: This graph is also not simple in the standard meaning of this term in graph theory, as those maps which _are_ graph homomorphisms have loops on them.

Answer (score 6):

Let $\textbf{Graph}$ be the category of (undirected) graphs. Consider a graph $I$ that consists of a single edge. Note that for every graph $G$ there exists a bijection
$$\mathrm{Hom}_{\textbf{Graph}}(I,G) \cong \mbox{ the set of edges of }G$$
natural in $G$. In other words the functor sending each graph to its set of edges is represented by $I$.

Let $pt$ be a graph with exactly one vertex. Then we have another natural bijection
$$\mathrm{Hom}_{\textbf{Graph}}(pt,G) \cong \mbox{ the set of vertices of }G$$

Suppose that $i_0,i_1:pt\rightarrow I$ are two distinct morphisms (endpoints of $I$).

Now pick graphs $G_1, G_2$ and let $\textbf{Hom}(G_1,G_2)$ be their exponential object (we assume that it exists). Then

$$\mathrm{Hom}_{\textbf{Graph}}(G_1\times I,G_2) \cong \mathrm{Hom}_{\textbf{Graph}}\left(I,\textbf{Hom}(G_1,G_2)\right) \cong \mbox{ the set of edges of }\textbf{Hom}(G_1,G_2)$$

So each edge in $\textbf{Hom}(G_1,G_2)$ corresponds uniquely to a morphism of graphs $f:G_1\times I \rightarrow G_2$. Now you can also verify that the edge corresponding to $f$ has precisely $f\cdot i_0,f\cdot i_1:G_1\cong G_1\times pt\rightarrow G_2$ as its endpoints.

This I think recovers the answer given by Tom Leinster above.

Comment: Thanks for this nice exposition @Slup!

Comment: @DominicvanderZypen I am happy that you find it useful.